# mvn install jar-with-dependencies

Tags: maven

Is there a way to do an install on a jar-with-dependencies created using maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: what do you mean by 'do an install on a jar-with-dependencies'?

Comment: the maven-assembly-plugin creates a jar which includes all dependencies. I want to install this into my local repo using mvn install.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your pom snippet

Comment: I think you may have to manually install the 'jar-with-dependencies' using this http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Pablacious's(one the second floor) method works. I change the jar package named by removing "-jar-with-dependency". It works,but not a elegant implementation. Anybody else have better implementation?

Answer (score 18):

If you bind the assembly to the packaging phase, it will install in your repository both the "regular" jar and the with-dependencies jar when you do a build:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!--  bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How to use that jar with dependencies then?

Comment: Important step for me:  I had to add `<archive><manifest><addClasspath>true</addClasspath><mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass></manifest></archive>` to the `<configuration>` node to get it to work properly because otherwise it did not know where my `main()` was

Answer (score 14):

mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies

:)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a project where you use the assembly-plugin. In the assembly-plugin configuration you can specify what output you want (jar, zip, ...)

In this projects pom you can put your dependencies and build it. Every time you execute the install command all your dependencies will be in your packaged file.

Answer (score 0):

Look under the heading "Executing: Building an Assembly" [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score -5):

Is `mvn install` not doing this?