# best way to include dependencies (jars) in build?

Tags: maven

What is currently the preferred way to include libraries (other jars) in the target jar?

I have tried assembly plugin with `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor, but it didn't produce the result I wanted. I just want the dependency jars copied inside the the target jar.

Comment: I just realized, that the easiest way to get jars to your target jar is to simply include them to 'src/main/resources'

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)'s [copy-dependenc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)y goal if that helps.
You would need to configure `outputDirectory` parameter, which by default is `target/dependency` folder.

Comment: this seems promising, but the artifact is copied to target/dependency after the target jar is created - hence it's not included in the jar

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ANT for your build scripts, the [JAR](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task allows you to include a [Fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) which you should be able to use to add your libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really using ANT for anything else, but if that's the only solution then that will do. -- But I'd still like to know if there is a "Maven Solution" for this

Comment: I should have paid more attention when reading the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) instead.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855530/332248).
(It will copy all class files of the dependencies into the resulting `jar` though. But maybe there is an option to copy the dependency jars directly?)